# Cite in Abstract before \begin{document}

Tags: bibtex, citing

I have my latex document finished and it compiles. 
But now I am stuck: 
Is it somehow possible to cite in the Abstract (before `\begin{document}`, and therefore before `\bibliography{bibliography_paper}`)? So far it only displays `Here I want to [?]`.

The structure of my document looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage{...}

\title{}

\author{}

\begin{abstract}
Here I want to~\cite{fooPaper}
\end{abstract}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{section:introduction}
\input{introduction}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{bibliography_paper}

\end{document}
```

I am using pdflatex and bibtex for compiling multiple times in a row (to resolve everything correctly).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What class requires you to have the abstract before `\begin{document}`? Anyway, without knowing it, it's impossible to help.

Comment: Are you sure that it requires *before `\begin{document}`* instead of *before `\maketitle`*?

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I moved the abstract into `\begin{document}` but before `\maketitle` as suggested by @Sigur, and now it works. I feel a little dumb now :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citations work by means of annotations made in the `.aux` file, which is

1. read in when `\begin{document}` is processed, in order to get the information collected in the previous LaTeX run
2. open for writing into at the end of processing `\begin{document}` in order to store information
3. read in again when `\end{document}` is processed

Thus `\cite` commands found before `\begin{document}` cannot find their way in the `.aux` file.

Put `abstract` *after* `\begin{document}`; it should go before `\maketitle` if the class you're using requires this, but not all classes do.